Profile selected functions in Python
I can profile and visualize my entire application with:
python -m cProfile -o program.prof my_program.py
snakeviz program.prof

Is it possible to write a decorator that will profile only some functions?
In the end this would look like this:
# This is the profiling decorator function.
def profile_function(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        
        # TODO write profiling information to program.prof
        
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@profile_function
def function1():
    for _ in range(0, 1000):
        _**2


@profile_function
def function2():
    for _ in range(0, 100000):
        _**4


# Do not profile function3
def function3():
    return


function1()
function2()
function3()


See Profile a section of code

@user19077881 thank you! I will have a look at this article. I need to understand how to write the information into one single file program.prof.
